# Prohibit multiple selection of NSMenuItems by cocoa binding

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, binding, nsmenuitem

I have multiple NSMenuItems in NSMenu. What I want to do is making only one of them being on state at the same time. (Just like single selection list box.)

The first option is to implement target/action methods for them and write code to do so.
But if possible I want to use cocoa binding to do this.

Here is what I want to do.

I have a single variable that can be set to 3 different values (0,1,2).
The number corresponds to the menu items(NSMenuItem0, NSMenuItem1, NSMenuItem2).
One of NSMenuItems here must be on state, and others must be off state.

So as initial state, NSMenuItem0 is on, NSMenuItem1 and NSMenuItem2 are off and the variable is 0. And if a user clicks NSMenuItem1, NSMenuItem0, NSMenuItem2 turn into off state and the variable is set to 1.

When the variable is set to 2 programatically, NSMenuItem2 should have check, and others shouldn't.

I tried to create 3 properties corresponds to each item's value to bind, and tried to customise the setter method but it didn't work because when user clicks a menu item which is already on state, the check is turned off. (I want to keep the check if user clicks an item that is already on state.)

The setter method I wrote is like this.

```
- (void)setItem0:(BOOL)b{
    if( _Item0 ){
        // It is already on state, don't want to change state.
        // But this doesn't affect to UI.
        // The internal variable is No but the NSMenuItem has check.
    }else{
        // Set other items to NO here ... (omit the code)
        // and change this property.
        _Item0 = enable; 
    }
}
```

I don't know if my approach is something totally wrong but I can't think of good way to achieve this.
Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: This is probably one of those times where it's easier to use an Action and implement the desired behavior without any Bindings in code. I tried to do it with Cocoa Bindings, but that just resulted in a lot of duplicated and ugly code and only made things more complicated.